# Seeking a formula for some rational polygons converging to the unit circle

Tags: numerical-methods, plane-geometry

I would like to know two series of rational polygons (in the sense of polygons with rational vertices) that converge to the unit circle.  More precisely one series P_n of rational polygons all contained in the circle and one series Q_n all containing the circle, such that the area of the n-th complement Q_n-P_n goes to 0.

For example: give a sequence of ever finer (finite) partitions of the circumference by rational points (using any parametrization of Pythagorean triples).  Each partition gives an inscribed polygon, and scaling that polygon up by a rational factor (which can get closer and closer to 1 as the number of sides rises) gives a polygon containing the circle.  Since the rational scalars approach 1, the areas of the inner and outer polygons converge.

But I do not want to work out some specific sequence of partitions for myself, and corresponding scalars, since I suspect simpler neater solutions are already known.

Is some simple way known?

Eventually i would also like to know higher dimensional analogues -- rational polytopes converging to the $n$-dimensional spheres.  But I will accept an answer for the 2-D case.

Comment: I think you need more than that the area of the difference goes to zero, since you could have a "spike" in $Q_N$ so that their areas converge but they don't converge e.g. in Hausdorff distance.

Comment: @Neal Oh, I think i first mistook your point in my first comment.  I am  asking about convergence in area (though I expect most natural solutions to my problem would also converge in all natural senses).

Comment: Well, the one in my answer does not converge in the Frechet topology for piecewise smooth functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an easily described solution, though it could obviously be improved for practical calculations. Consider the first quadrant of the circle.  For each natural number $n$ partition the arc at $n$ points, namely the  intersections of the circle with the lines from the point $\langle 0,-1\rangle$ to the points $\langle i/n, 0\rangle$ as $i$ ranges from $0$ to $n$.  Then the inner Riemann sum (i.e. using rectangles, each with its upper right corner at a partition point) gives a polygon contained in the circle, while the outer one gives a polygon containing the circle.  A simple calculation shows these inner and outer polygons come as close to each other as desired when $n$ goes to infinity.

Namely for any $d>0$ take $n$ with $1/n<d/2$.  The difference between the inner and outer sums for this $n$ is less than $d$.

For verification notice for fixed $n$, the $x$ coordinates of the partition points are $2in/(n^2+i^2)$.  These intervals have monotone decreasing length as you go from $0$ to $1$.  (One proof: $2x/(1+x^2)$ has negative second derivative all over $[0,1]$.)  So the left Riemann sum for this partition exceeds the right Riemann sum by less than the area of the first summand in the left Riemann sum, and that is  $2/n$.